# Generic Makefile for Qt Project

Tags: c++, qt, makefile

I'm currently workind on a project for my school. It's a snake game which will work with 3 differents graphics.

It works fine, but I want to add a Qt touch in order to display a Window when the game is over. I already built the window, but now I need to merge this with my project, and my project has to compile with a Makefile. The problem is that I don't know if I can build my project with a unique Makefile. I usually use qmake -project, qmake, and make to build my Qt projects.

Thnks for your help

Comment: qmake generates a Makefile, are you not allowed to use it?

Comment: Nope .. That's the difficult part, and I'm using SDL, Opengl and SFML in my current project

Comment: why not separate them to other makefiles and use the qmake one to link together?

Comment: @Nicolas well, you should be able to manually write a Makefile for your project, though be aware that for Qt you need to call the moc, a quick google search brought [this](https://gist.github.com/mishurov/8134532) up, might be useful for you

Comment: It looks like it could work, but with this Makefile it doesn't compile, #include <QObject> no such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no universal `Makefile`, it will always vary depending on what platform you use, where Qt is installed, what Qt libraries you link and many other things.

For this simple `main.cpp`:

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QPushButton button("Hello");
    button.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

`Makefile` could be:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4
LIBS=-lQtGui -lQtCore

app: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) $< -o $@
```

If you also need signals and slots, you need to add a separate target to `Makefile` to run `moc`. Try to investigate what `qmake` generates and learn from it.